# Is there a way to open an encrypted Oracle Database wallet through weblogic JDBC drivers?

Tags: oracle, java, jdbc, transparent-data-encryption

I encrypted a column in an Oracle 12c database using the TDE method, The said column was being used in my application, The column becomes unavailable due to the Database wallet being closed.

To open the wallet I use the command 'ADMINISTER KEY MANAGEMENT SET KEYSTORE OPEN IDENTIFIED BY password;'

If I open the Database encryption wallet the column becomes available and the application works fine.

As the application is being deployed using weblogic servers, I was wondering if it is possible to open the wallet with the help of JDBC driver, or is there some way to pass the wallet password so as to open the wallet on connection to the database.

Comment: Are you sure your database is 11g? The ADMINISTER KEY MANAGEMENT sentence is used beginning from 12cR1 for keystore management, rather than wallet openning/close management with ALTER SYSTEM or auto-login wallets which was the method used in 11g. Both methods are quite different